# I'm trying to run a line of code that pulls a status count from a dataframe, the results of which will render above my pandas html table

Tags: python, html, css, pandas

#Here is the sample dataframe first:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    data = [['001', 'Completed'], ['002', 'In Process'], ['003', 'Not Started'], ['004''Completed'], 
    ['005', 'In Process'],['006', 'Completed'], ['007', 'Not Started']] 

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Order', 'Status']) 
    df1

    Not_Started = np.sum(df1['Status'] == 'Not Started')

    In_Process =  np.sum(df1['Status'] == 'In Process')

    Completed =  np.sum(df1['Status'] == 'Completed')

    df1_status = df1['Status'].value_counts().to_frame()   

    df1_status = df1_status.append(df1_status.sum().rename('Total'))
    print(df1_status)

    Total = df1['Status'].count()
```

#Then I create my html table:

```
    pd.set_option('colheader_justify', 'center')   

    html_string = '''
    <html>
      <head><title>HTML Pandas Dataframe with CSS</title></head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="df_style.css"/>
      <body>
        <h1 style="text-align:center"> STATUS BOARD </h1>
        {table}
      </body>
    </html>.
    '''
```

## OUTPUT AN HTML FILE

```
    with open('myhtml.html', 'w') as f:
        f.write(html_string.format(table=df1.to_html(classes='mystyle', na_rep='', index = False)))
```

#This is the string that I need to render above my table:

```
    status = "{} of {} Completed".format(Completed, Total)
```

#I will include my css stylesheet at the bottom, but do not know how to attach it.
#I apologize if I did not format the question properly. This is only my second time asking a question on #here, so any formatting suggestions/corrections or code cleanup are greatly appreciated.

```
    /* includes alternating gray and white with on-hover color */

.mystyle {
    font-size: 15pt; 
    font-family: Arial;
    border-collapse: collapse; 
    border: 1px solid silver;
}
           
.mystyle td, th {
    padding: 10px;
}

.mystyle tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #E0E0E0;
}

.mystyle tr:hover {
    background: silver;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.mystyle {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.mystyle {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Your code looks correct and `status = "{} of {} Completed".format(Completed, Total)` is right,  I don't understand what is wrong or what you need to fix

Comment: As of now, I cannot render the 'status' output above my table. I have them working separately great, but after a ton of research, I cannot find a way to call that variable and have it appear below 'STATUS BOARD' and above the table on that html page.

Comment: This is an example of a much larger manufacturing dataframe that I have updating from an ERP system using scan guns to track the progress of work orders from 'Not Started' to 'Complete.' This count will update every minute, and the count will change as work orders are completed. I then send this html to a raspberry pi that renders on a huge tv so the men and women doing the work can view in (near)-real time how many are completed of the total work orders currently active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this code but if I understand correctly, the code might look like this:

```
pd.set_option('colheader_justify', 'center')   

table = df1.to_html(classes='mystyle', na_rep='', index = False)
status = f"{Completed} of {Total} Completed"

html_string = f'''
<html>
    <head><title>HTML Pandas Dataframe with CSS</title></head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="df_style.css"/>
    <body>

    <h1 style="text-align:center"> STATUS BOARD </h1>
    <h3>{status}</h3>
    {table}

    <script>setInterval(() => location.reload(), 60000);</script>
    </body>
</html>.
'''
```

Every minute rewrite .html file

```
import time

while True:
    with open('myhtml.html', 'w') as f:
        f.write(html_string)
    time.sleep(60)
```

Because in the .html file there is a script for reloading the page every minute, we overwrite the file and after reloading the changes will be displayed on the page

Comment: That did the trick perfectly. I really appreciate you taking the time to add the code for updating the script as well.